# Localstack running aws lambda (python) with sqlalchemy filter query - causes exception

Tags: python, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy, localstack

I created an AWS lambda function that uses sqlalchemy to connect to a mysql database.

The code runs **successfully** both on my development station (lambda function called from main), and from AWS itself as a lambda.

I am building a test using localstack docker. I created the lambda on localstack and then invoked it. The sqlalchemy query to the database **fails** with an exception. If I modify the sqlalchemy query to a simple query, it works ok.

***NOTE:** See a possible workaround in my answer.*

The function that fails is `get_rows_by_status_and_age` and this is the lambda code:

```
db_connection_str=f'mysql+pymysql://{db_user}:{db_pass}@{db_host}/{db_schema}'

def db_init():
    engine = create_engine(db_connection_str, echo=False, isolation_level="READ COMMITTED")
    # logger.info(db_connection_str)
    # logger.info(engine.dialect)
    sm = sessionmaker(bind=engine, expire_on_commit=False)
    session = sm()
    return engine, session

def get_rows_by_status_and_age(session, status_list, min_age_minutes):
    time_current = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
    time_old = time_current - datetime.timedelta(minutes=min_age_minutes)
    try:
        q = session.query(func.count(Execution.id)).filter(
            Execution.status.in_(status_list),
            Execution.updated_at < time_old)
        return q.scalar()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("failed with error: {}".format(e))
        raise

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    engine, session = db_init()
    try:
        count = get_rows_by_status_and_age(session, [1,6,7], 20)
        logger.info(count)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.info('Error in the lambda:')
        logger.exception(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':  # pragma: no cover
    logging.basicConfig()
    lambda_handler("", "")
```

The exception for the above query is a `KeyError`:

```
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T08:00:48:ERROR:root: failed with error: <function comma_op at 0x7fd9677e0440>
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T08:00:48:INFO:root: Error in the lambda:
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T08:00:48:ERROR:root: <function comma_op at 0x7fd9677e0440>
localstack_container            | Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/lambda_script_l_656d31ba.py", line 43, in lambda_handler
localstack_container            |     count = get_rows_by_status_and_age(session, [1,6,7], 20)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/lambda_script_l_656d31ba.py", line 29, in get_rows_by_status_and_age
localstack_container            |     return q.scalar()
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3312, in scalar
localstack_container            |     ret = self.one()
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3282, in one
localstack_container            |     ret = self.one_or_none()
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3251, in one_or_none
localstack_container            |     ret = list(self)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3324, in __iter__
localstack_container            |     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3349, in _execute_and_instances
localstack_container            |     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
localstack_container            |     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1098, in _execute_clauseelement
localstack_container            |     else None,
localstack_container            |   File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 462, in compile
localstack_container            |     return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 468, in _compiler
localstack_container            |     return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 562, in __init__
localstack_container            |     Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 319, in __init__
localstack_container            |     self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 350, in process
localstack_container            |     return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2092, in visit_select
localstack_container            |     for name, column in select._columns_plus_names
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2092, in <listcomp>
localstack_container            |     for name, column in select._columns_plus_names
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1845, in _label_select_column
localstack_container            |     return result_expr._compiler_dispatch(self, **column_clause_args)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 820, in visit_label
localstack_container            |     + self.preparer.format_label(label, labelname)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 826, in visit_label
localstack_container            |     self, within_columns_clause=False, **kw
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1105, in visit_function
localstack_container            |     ) % {"expr": self.function_argspec(func, **kwargs)}
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1117, in function_argspec
localstack_container            |     return func.clause_expr._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 718, in visit_grouping
localstack_container            |     return "(" + grouping.element._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs) + ")"
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.b3651fa4/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 968, in visit_clauselist
localstack_container            |     sep = OPERATORS[clauselist.operator]
localstack_container            | KeyError: <function comma_op at 0x7fd9677e0440>
```

If I modify the query to the following query, it also fails but with a different exception (I removed the func.count()):

```
        q = session.query(Execution.id).filter(
            Execution.status.in_(status_list),
            Execution.updated_at < time_old)
        return q.all()
```

In the last case the exception is a `UnsupportedCompilationError` as follows:

```
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T09:44:20:ERROR:root: failed with error: Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb.MySQLCompiler_mysqldb object at 0x7fb84801d9d0> can't render element of type <function in_op at 0x7fb8464b0b90> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/l7de)
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T09:44:20:INFO:root: Error in the lambda:
localstack_container            | 2021-08-24T09:44:20:ERROR:root: Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb.MySQLCompiler_mysqldb object at 0x7fb84801d9d0> can't render element of type <function in_op at 0x7fb8464b0b90> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/l7de)
localstack_container            | Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1281, in visit_binary
localstack_container            |     opstring = OPERATORS[operator_]
localstack_container            | KeyError: <function in_op at 0x7fb8464b0b90>
localstack_container            | 
localstack_container            | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
localstack_container            | 
localstack_container            | Traceback (most recent call last):
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/lambda_script_l_a11f462d.py", line 46, in lambda_handler
localstack_container            |     count = get_rows_by_status_and_age(session, [1,6,7], 20)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/lambda_script_l_a11f462d.py", line 32, in get_rows_by_status_and_age
localstack_container            |     return q.all()
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3168, in all
localstack_container            |     return list(self)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3324, in __iter__
localstack_container            |     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3349, in _execute_and_instances
localstack_container            |     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
localstack_container            |     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1098, in _execute_clauseelement
localstack_container            |     else None,
localstack_container            |   File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 462, in compile
localstack_container            |     return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 468, in _compiler
localstack_container            |     return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 562, in __init__
localstack_container            |     Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 319, in __init__
localstack_container            |     self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 350, in process
localstack_container            |     return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2117, in visit_select
localstack_container            |     text, select, inner_columns, froms, byfrom, kwargs
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2216, in _compose_select_body
localstack_container            |     t = select._whereclause._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 972, in visit_clauselist
localstack_container            |     c._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw) for c in clauselist.clauses
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 970, in <genexpr>
localstack_container            |     s
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 972, in <genexpr>
localstack_container            |     c._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw) for c in clauselist.clauses
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 91, in _compiler_dispatch
localstack_container            |     return meth(self, **kw)
localstack_container            |   File "/tmp/localstack/zipfile.183ee235/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 1283, in visit_binary
localstack_container            |     raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(self, operator_)
localstack_container            | sqlalchemy.exc.UnsupportedCompilationError: Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqldb.MySQLCompiler_mysqldb object at 0x7fb84801d9d0> can't render element of type <function in_op at 0x7fb8464b0b90> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/l7de)
```

If I leave only the single filter it works:

```
        q = session.query(Execution.id).filter(
            Execution.updated_at < time_old)
        return q.all()
```

From trying to understand the problem, it appears as a problem with compiling a query due maybe to database-dependant syntax, but I printed out the sqlalchemy dialect and it is mysql, like it should be. And like I mentioned it works fine in all other environments other than localstack lambda.

It seems to be caused somehow by localstack env.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the `status` column?  Can you share how it is declared in the model?

Comment: @snakecharmerb quite trivial: `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, - I doubt this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an answer but a possible **workaround**.

Localstack has an option to execute lambda functions in a separate docker. Using this configuration, the sqlalchemy error does not happen and the the lambda runs successfully.

In order to have localstack invoke lambda functions in a separate docker, you use the LAMBDA_EXECUTOR environment variable when you start the localstack docker.

In docker-compose it will look something like this:

```
services:
  ...
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      ...
      LAMBDA_EXECUTOR: docker
      LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK: testing_network
    ...
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    ...
    container_name: localstackcontainer
  ...
```

Explanation:

- LAMBDA_EXECUTOR - Tell localstack to run lambdas in separate docker.
- LAMBDA_DOCKER_NETWORK - Tell localstack to add the separate docker to a specific docker network. (You will typically add it to the docker network where all your services are running, to allow communication over the docker network). ("testing_network" in my example)
- Volume mapping /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock - This allows localstack docker to start a new docker on your host.
- Note: Lambda code will now connect to other aws services in the localstack, using as the endpoint_url the localstack container name (to connect over docker network). In my example it is "localstackcontainer:4566" (instead of localhost:4566 when lambda runs inside the localstack docker itself).
  Note that this required me to change the localstack container name from localstack_container to localstackcontainer because aws endpoint cannot contain underscore.